# How can I make a Chrome extension automatically click a button when a page loads?

Tags: javascript, button, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I'm trying to create a Google Chrome extension that presses a button on page load. I've been able to trigger the button using VBscript for Internet Explorer by using this code:

```
IE.Navigate("javascript:changeIframe();")
```

But, now I need to do it in Google Chrome via an extension. However, the button does not have an id:

```
<input type="button" value="Start!" onclick="javascript:changeIframe();">
```

and here's what I've tried so far and nothing seems to work:

```
window.onload="javascript:changeIframe()";
javascript:changeIframe();
document.getElementById('').click();
document.getElementById('').submit();
```

It seems that `.click` and `.submit` is not defined in Google-Chrome's javascript?

The weird thing is that when I use this script:

```
javascript:changeIframe();
```

in Chrome's javascript console, it presses the button automatically and everything works fine. But, when I put the same script in my .js file it does not work.

I just need to know what I have to put inside my .js in order to press the button automatically on page load.

Comment: Not sure why you'd bother using VBScript since it'll only work in IE.

Comment: i could do anything i wanted with IE and it worked fine but IE wont let me to run more that 30 instances simultaneously thats the reason why i moved to google chrome

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The traditional way to do this is to *inject* the code<sup>1</sup>:

```
var scriptNode          = document.createElement ('script');
scriptNode.textContent  = 'changeIframe ();';

document.body.appendChild (scriptNode);
```

You won't normally have to listen for `onload` either, as content scripts will fire roughly at that point by default.

<sup>1</sup> The extension JS operates in an "Isolated World" and cannot interact with the page's javascript without some tricks that are not needed here.

Comment: It worked !It worked ,oh my god , ive been dealing with this issue for one month and you just solved it for me ,thank you, thank you so much,

Comment: i just dont know how thank you , whats your email i have to send you an amazon gift card for what youve done for me  , oh my god i just cant believe it worked

Answer (score 8):

Great that you got a solution, but thought Id show you another way of simulating a click.
With this way you dont have to inject code or know the function that the onclick will run, just get the button and simulate a click....

```
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.dispatchEvent
function simulateClick(obj) {
  var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
  evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
  var canceled = !obj.dispatchEvent(evt);      
/*

  if(canceled) {
    // A handler called preventDefault
    alert("canceled");
  } else {
    // None of the handlers called preventDefault
    alert("not canceled");
  }
  */
}

var what = document.querySelector('input[type="button"][value="Start!"]');
simulateClick(what);
```

Comment: It helps me with my task. I been looking the way to "click" on a class with role="button". Thanks!