# Automatic click using javascript on webpage

Tags: javascript, web, click

I am currently experimenting something, and I became to have to click a button on a website which I didn't make, automatically using files made up of javascript and other web languages.

I read this one: [How do I programmatically click a link with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902713/how-do-i-programmatically-click-a-link-with-javascript)

But if I want to auto-click a website which I didn't make, so I can't get access to the website's files. Then, should (or can) I load the website's .php or .html and attach my snippets which contain document.getElementById('yourLinkID').click(); ?

If I can load the website's files, and attach my code and make it run,
How can I do that? 
Or is there other possible ways?

Since I try to click a site whose files aren't accessible, I can't figure out how can I click button

Comment: Open the page in your browser (let's say Google Chrome), press F12 to open browser console and run the following: `document.getElementById('yourLinkID').click()`

Comment: You can try to load the external page in an iframe. Via the iFrame-Handle you may get access to the dom-elements.

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways I can think of:

1. Open the 'developer tools' in your browser, and copy & paste your snippets there.
2. Create a [Chrome plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387615/how-can-i-make-a-chrome-extension-automatically-click-a-button-when-a-page-loads) to attach the snippets and click the link.
3. Run something like [Selenium ChromeDriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started), and instruct it to go to the site mentioned and execute the `document.getElementByid('yourLinkID').click()`